# NSService define hotkey programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

My app declares a service and I'd like to allow users to set the hotkey for that service from within my app's Preferences (so that I won't have to direct users to System Preferences).

Is there any way of declaring the service programmatically (or just the hotkey), or is the Info.plist the only way?

Comment: Interested to see if this is possible. Only way I have seen it done with a hotkey (that does not show in the menu item) is extremely hacky.